# Camera.RenderWithShader function doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, game-engine, unity-game-engine

I currently work on a project in Unity 5. I am trying to apply a shader to one of my cameras using `Camera.RenderWithShader`, and after that read and save the image. Here is the code:

```
Texture2D screenshot = new Texture2D(this.screenWidth, this.screenHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
this.mainCamera.RenderWithShader(this.myShader,"RenderType");
screenshot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, this.cameraWidth, this.cameraHeight), 0, 0);
```

The problem is that, after I save the screenshot texture as a Bitmap, the shader is not applied on the entire image.

But if I use `Camera.Render()` and apply the shader using `OnRenderImage(RenderTexture,RenderTexture)`, it works.

```
void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{
     Graphics.Blit(source, destination, this.disparityMaterial);
}
```

So, my question is: What is the difference between these two approaches and how can I make the `Camera.RenderWithShader` function work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RenderWithShader](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.RenderWithShader.html) and [OnRenderImage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html) are two completely different things and have nothing to do with each other.
Read the linked manual pages for details and a better understand, but long story short:
*Prior* is applying a shader to all (game)objects the camera can see  *without* any image filters applied so basically it's about using a different shader for the same objects/prefabs/materials to alter something the way you want for the viewer (in your case, GOs should also have their tag set to "RenderType", otherwise the shader will not be applied on them),
*Latter* one however is a "post processing" feature, applying filters *only* on images already rendered. I.e. an [image effect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-ImageEffects.html) feature.
So a good use to prior one is e.g. nightvision on/off, or remove cloth from chicks with that special glasses the player can put hands on (mmmmm), etc while the latter one is clearly just image effects, e.g. a secret agent takes photos while one-finger-kills enemies, but when he gets hit, his equipment is more and more damaged, so photos taken as intel are getting more and more blurry, broken up and such - if that makes sense.